# Data of Array is converting into characters in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the PHP response (Array) index wise in log of Javascript. I tried multiple times. On changing it into `JSON.parse(value)`, it alert the whole data. But on the console, it prints character wise data.
On parseing for console `console.log(JSON.parse(value));` it prompts;

```
VM2461:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at String.<anonymous> (index.html:38)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (index.html:36)
    at o (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.min.js:4)
```

**PHP code**

```
$test = array("hello","world","hi");
echo json_encode($test);
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test.php",
    type:"POST",
    async:true,
    data:{
        "searchDat" : searchDat,
        },
    success: function(data){
        alert( JSON.parse(data));
        //alert(data[0]);
        $.each(data, function(ind, value){
           console.log(value);
           //console.log(JSON.parse(value));
        });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is the JSON string, not the array, so `$.each` is iterating over the characters in the string. You should put the result of `JSON.parse()` into a variable, and loop over that.

```
success: function(data) {
    var array = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(array, function(ind,value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

You can also use `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` options, and jQuery will parse the JSON automatically for you; then `data` will contain the array.